# Most commonly used word in column of a view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there a way to get the most commonly used word from a view..
For example, if I have a column with names like this

```
NAME
John
Mary
Jane
Alan
John
Laura
John
```

It will return `John` because it is the name that appears the most.

*Added...*

I don't mind using another view as suggested by @Richard Schwartz. In fact, I created it and tried something similar but a little different than your first suggestion.

Here is my code, but it doesn't return the correct value:

```
Dim var As Variant
Set view1 = db2.getView("pomoc")
var=view1.GetColumnValues(0)
max=-1
field=""
Forall id In var
    Set ve=view1.GetEntryByKey(id)
    num=ve.ChildCount
    If num>max Then     
        max=num
        field=id
    End If  
End Forall
```

And I also want to register the entries that are used the same number of times

Comment: I've moved your follow-up from your answer into a revision of your question.

Comment: Well, since NotesView.getColumnValues is undocumented, I really can't say what the above code should do. On the assumptions that GetColumnValues returns one value per category, and that GetEntryByKey returns the category entry for that key rather than a document entry, then it looks like it should work. But you say it doesn't get you the correct result (without saying what it actually does get you), so why not follow my original suggestion of using a NotesViewNavigator to walk the categories - using GetFirst and GetNextCategory?

Comment: I didn't use it the first place because I wasn't sure how.. After some research I come up with this
    `Dim var As NotesViewEntry`
    `Set var=nav.GetFirst()`
 `max=-1`
 `Do While Not var Is Nothing`
 `num=var.ChildCount`
 `If num>max Then`
 `max=num`
 `End If`
 `Set var=nav.GetNextCategory(var)`
 `Loop`
 `Print var.ColumnValues(0)`

But I don't know how to access the category name - the last line of code gives the error: "Object varible not set"

Comment: I solved this error by putting `var.ColumnValues(0)` inside the do..while loop. And it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you okay with adding another view? Make it categorized, and then write your code to use a `NotesViewNavigator` to walk the categories, looking for the `NotesViewEntry` with the highest `ChildCount`.

If you are unable to add another view, then you will probably have to use a List:

```
dim names List as integer
```

Then write your code to get NotesView.AllEntries, use GetFirstEntry and GetNextEntry to walk the NotesViewEntryCollection, and for each NotesViewEntry execute statements like this:

```
thisName = thisEntry.ColumnValues(N)
names(thisName) = names(thisName) + 1
```

Where N is the columnn containing the names.

After you've processed the entire view, do something like this:

```
maxCount = 0
maxName = ""
forall nameCounter in names
 if nameCounter > maxCount then
   maxCount = nameCounter
   maxName = listtag(nameCounter)
end forall
```

When this exits, maxName will be the most common name, and maxCount will be the number of occurrances.